# jQuery Dialog button change color inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using this code, and I want to change the color of each button inline, because i'm using custom classes for dialog, buttons etc. and I don't want to touch them.

```
$(function() {
  $colorDialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: 'customDialogClass',
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: [
      {
        TODO: change color
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          processResult("color");
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the css via [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) too.

```
click: function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    $(this).dialog("close");
    processResult("color");
}
```

(I am assuming, that you want to change the color of the button that was clicked.)

Comment: I have inside the dialog in the body buttons and I want to change their color. It's not working because $(this) in above scope is for all dialog, and I need only the button inside it...

Comment: Well then change `$(this)` to whatever jquery-(css)-selector you need?
`$('#dialog .your-css-class').css('background-color', '#FF0000');`. I am no visionary and do not know your html-structure.